# Are there more zero-false-negative filter algorithms like bloom filter?

Tags: algorithm

I'm using zero-false-negative filter algorithm to accelerate data block scanning, and I wonder if there are more filter algorithms suitable for this scenario.

I use the algorithm like this:

```
if data-block doesn't contain item 
    skip data-block
else
    scan data-block
```

Item maybe an integer, decimal, string. Data-block is an array of items with same type.

I have found several filter algorithms with zero false negative rate:

- bloom, cuckoo and xor filter and their variants
- min max filter, only useful for integer and decimal
- cmap for string

Does anyone heard of any other filter algorithms?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's off topic

Comment: Implementing a Van-Emde-Boas tree without the actual data can also be used to check for the presence of or absence off some data.

Comment: I’m familiar with Bloom, cuckoo, and XOR filters but not min max filters or cmaps. Can you point me at some references for those?

Comment: For strings, there’s also the Rabin-Karp algorithm based on fingerprinting with rolling hashes.